# Multithreading 1D Median Filtering in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, matlab, numpy, median

I have tried the following python median filtering on **time-series signals** to find the fastest and more efficient function.

`sig` is a `numpy` array of size `80×188` which contains 188 samples measured by 80 sensors.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import median_filter
from scipy.signal import medfilt
from scipy.signal import medfilt2d
import time

sig = np.random.rand(80,188).astype('f')
print(type(sig))
print(type(sig[0][0]))


window_length = 181

t = time.time()
sigFiltered = medfilt2d(sig, (1,window_length))
elapsed = time.time() - t
print('scipy.signal.medfilt2d: %g seconds' % elapsed)

t = time.time()
sigFiltered = median_filter(sig, (1,window_length))
elapsed = time.time() - t
print('scipy.ndimage.median_filter: %g seconds' % elapsed)

t = time.time()
sigFiltered = medfilt(sig, (1,window_length))
elapsed = time.time() - t
print('scipy.signal.medfilt: %g seconds' % elapsed)
```

The code can be tried [here](https://onlinegdb.com/r1UGREi7I).

The result of the filter is another time-series array of size `80×188` with smoothed time-points for each sensor.

MATLAB [`medfilt1`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/medfilt1.html)`(sig, 181, [], 2)` performs the filtering on the same data 10 times faster compared to [`scipy.signal.medfilt2d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.medfilt2d.html), which was the fastest among other functions. On my machine, MATLAB=2ms vs Python=20 ms. I think MATLAB performs multithreading processing and python does not.

Is there any way to perform multithreading median filtering to speed up the process and assign sensors to different threads? Is there a more efficient median filtering available in python? Can I achieve the performance of MATLAB win python or at least get closer to it?

Comment: How fast do you need it to be?

Comment: Less than 1 milliseconds.

Comment: And the filter length should be 181? Is this a time series where you get 80x185 samples of data every 1ms?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With such a long filter relative to the input most outputs using a standard medfilt are going to be the same. Where this to be a convolution this would be a "full" convolution. If you instead only give outputs for "valid" convolution, that will be much faster in this case:

```py
t = time.time()
medians = []
for i in range(188-181):
    sig2 = sig[:, i:i+window_length]
    f = np.median(sig2, axis=1)
    medians.append(f)

sigFiltered = np.stack(medians).T
elapsed = time.time() - t
print('numpy.median: %g seconds' % elapsed)
```

```sh
numpy.median: 0.0015518 seconds
```

This is in the ballpark of the requested 1 ms runtime per 188 sample size.

Considering that even each unique value here will change very slowly/rarely with new input samples. You could therefore speed this up considerably by using a hop larger than 1.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Here is the timing on my machine: `scipy.signal.medfilt2d: 0.146966 seconds`, `scipy.ndimage.median_filter: 0.164019 seconds`, `scipy.signal.medfilt: 0.337012 seconds`, `numpy.median: 0.329585 seconds`. Using your proposed solution, it takes much longer compared to other functions.

Comment: :s that does not make sense, that should be a very very fast function. Could you try 100 repeats, and report the median time? May be that the process gets interrupted by the OS, in which case anything will look to be slow

Comment: The result is in agreement to your profiling: `scipy.signal.medfilt2d: 0.023031 seconds`, `scipy.ndimage.median_filter: 0.0299957 seconds`, `scipy.signal.medfilt: 0.191031 seconds`, `numpy.median: 0.00196528 seconds`.

Comment: In your expert opinion, do you think there is room for further efficiency? Can it be threaded without sacrificing performance?

Comment: Multi-threading is unlikely to help here. Python has the GIL which prevents multi-threading, so it would have to be done in C/C++. And anyway the task is quite small relative to the startup time of threads. Could be dedicated median algorithm in C/C++ operating on numpy arrays would be faster than the generic one in numpy. But I would expect I/O to quickly become the bottleneck in this application, with 1000 Hz input rate. So would look higher up in the stack before optimizing more

Answer (score -2):

I'm wondering why you're using a median filter of 181 points for a data length of 188? The filter is so long that you're essentially just throwing away all the data and replacing it with the global median of the sensor's output. Typical median filter lengths would be a few samples, depending on what kind of transients you want to filter out.

The filter length also explains why it's so slow. On my machine, your `median_filter` example takes 46 ms. Running with a more normal filter size of 3 samples takes 0.7 ms.